# Singulae aut unae scopae?

Tags: grammar-choice, numbers, plural

Tuomo Pekkanen's grammar (§92.1) explains how to express the number of something that is expressed by a plural-only word.
Numbers greater than one are expressed with *bini, trini* etc. but a single one is not *singuli*.
The cardinal number *unus* is used instead.

For example: *unae scopae, binae scopae, trinae scopae…*
(The actual example given in the book is *una castra*.)

This strikes me as odd.
But then again, Latin grammar is occasionally odd.
I would like to have verification or falsification for this rule.
Are there classical use examples like "one broom" (*unae/singulae scopae*)?
What do other modern grammarians say on the topic?
Is *unae* correct and *singulae* incorrect?

Perhaps the neuter plural *una* (as used in the book's sole example) looks a little less suspicious than *unae*, but I still find it weird.

Comment: On a tangential point, your “occasionally odd” comment invoked my reading of the Lomonosov's 18th c. grammar of Russian, one of those first describing the modern language. If I understand him, a distributive numeral is used for people, unless the whole group is all-female. But it gets worse than that. He notes it would be "impolite" to use a distributive when referring to (male) persons of noble status, so "two dukes" or "three archbishops" call for a cardinal, not a distributive. And Arabic inverses numeral's *gender* in some cases. Latin is *amazingly* regular compared to these!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tricky thing to explain, but:

*Unus* is the cardinal 'one', which has plural forms that are used with plural-form nouns such as *castra* and *scopae*. In such cases it is proper to write *una castra* or *unae scopae*.

*Singulus* is used distributively — 'one for each', and so on — and is not to be confused with *singularis*, 'single' when an adjectival use is intended.

Rather confusingly, the distributive forms of numerals are used as if cardinals when describing more than one of the plural-form nouns. Thus, *singulae scopae* and *binae scopae* refer to the numbers of separate brooms, while *unae scopae* is (just) one broom.